# Activity Background color for AppBarLayout shadow

Tags: android, android-layout

AppBarLayout by default has an elevation but shadow is not visible(or maybe it is visible but not as prominent as the one with orange background[See below]) on default background colour of the activity as you can see below the shadow is not visible.

[image]

But when I change the background colour to one which matches the color of AppBarLayout the shadow is visible as shown in picture below.

[image]

I feel this has something to do with the transparency of background colour. I want an elevation with white background which looks similar as youtube android app. What  should I do?
[image]

Comment: Did you try to set `android:elavation="0dp"`?

Comment: @Skullper Why should I put this attribute when I need an elevation on AppBarLayout ?

Comment: The shadow exists in both snapshots.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. There is clearly a shadow in the first picture

Comment: @Anfuca Then why isn't the background colour visible so clearly as in the one with orange background. If you see the youtube android app you can see the black shadow even on white backround. How to achieve similar shadow ?

Comment: that's matter of contrast I guess. If you want more shadow, increase the elevation

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0)???

Comment: @Tim I will try increasing the elevation and respond to you soon.

Comment: @godot Why should I set the elevation to zero when I want the shadow to be casted. Tim is asking me to increase elevation and you are asking it to set to zero. Why ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I increased the elevation with `android:elevation=24dp` but still it looks similar to picture I have added but when I use `app:elevation=24dp` no elevation is present(I checked it with orange background). I don't think it has something to do with the elevation magnitude but it is something to do with background color because as soon as I change the color to orange that black colour shadow is visible.

Comment: The shadow is always visible. Your problem isn't really a problem